# Invalid conversion from throwing function. When use decoder class

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, exception, compiler-errors

I am using decoder class for parsing the json response of firebase firestore.

This is extension which I am using for parsing:

```
extension DocumentSnapshot {
    func toObject<T: Decodable>() throws -> T {
        
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data()!, options: [])
        let object = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: jsonData)
        
        return object
    }
}
```

But when I am fetching documents from the list of document id.

Then I am getting this error:

```
Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(DocumentSnapshot?, Error?) throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '(DocumentSnapshot?, Error?) -> Void'
```

This is my function where I am using DocumentSnapshot extension method 'toObject'

```
    plasmaRequestIDs.forEach { (document) in
        
        Firestore.firestore().collection("plasma_request").document(document).addSnapshotListener { (documentSnapshot, error) in
            
            
            guard let err = error else{return}
            
            guard let snapshot = documentSnapshot else {return}
            
            if snapshot.exists{
                
                
                let requestobj:PlasmaRequest =  try snapshot.toObject()
                plasmaRequestList.append(requestobj)
                
                if index == plasmaRequestIDs.count - 1 {
                    
                    successHandler(plasmaRequestList)
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
        index = index + 1
    }
```

I am getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at `FirebaseFirestoreSwift`'s built-in custom object support? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects

Answer (score 2):

I’m just going to explain the "invalid conversion" error, because that’s all you asked about. The terminology is a little confusing, but the underlying issue is perfectly clear.

You will admit, I think, that your `toObject` is a throwing function? Note the word `throws`:

```
func toObject<T: Decodable>() throws -> T {
```

And you therefore rightly acknowledge that fact when you call it, by calling it with `try`:

```
let requestobj:PlasmaRequest =  try snapshot.toObject()
```

Okay, but Swift is very strict about where you can say that; you can only say `try` in two places:

- In the `do` of a `do/catch` structure
- In a `throws` function

But you are in neither of those! You are in this:

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("plasma_request")
    .document(document)
        .addSnapshotListener { 
            (documentSnapshot, error) in
```

The closure to `.addSnapshotListener` does not throw. So that option is removed. Therefore what's left? You *must* do one of the following:

- Wrap your call to `toObject` in the `do` of a `do/catch`
- Use `try?` instead of `try`
- Use `try!` instead of `try`

I recommend the first one.